# Recovering mysql case sensitive fulltext search after dropping index

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database where I deleted the fulltext index on a column. After re-adding it, I cannot get back the same original behavior.

Here's an example.

I create the table and set the character set to `utf8_bin`. I also add a fulltext index:

```sh
CREATE TABLE testtable (
             `Date` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
             `Headline` VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
             `Description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`Headline`)
            );
ALTER TABLE testtable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
ALTER TABLE testtable ADD FULLTEXT (Headline);
```

I add some dummy data:

```sh
INSERT INTO testtable (Headline,Description) VALUES ("the story of how an apple fell from the tree",""); 
INSERT INTO testtable (Headline,Description) VALUES ("Apple did something blah","");
```

Now if I search:

```sh
SELECT `Date`,`Headline` FROM testtable WHERE MATCH (Headline) AGAINST ('apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

```
'2020-02-19 17:16:05', 'the story of how an apple fell from the tree'
```

and

```sh
SELECT `Date`,`Headline` FROM testtable WHERE MATCH (Headline) AGAINST ('Apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

```
'2020-02-19 17:18:38', 'Apple did something blah'
```

Great, that works, and **that is the result I want**.

Now let's drop the index, re-add it, and try that again:

```sh
DROP INDEX Headline ON testtable;
#ALTER TABLE testtable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin; # I also tried this with no difference
ALTER TABLE testtable ADD FULLTEXT (Headline);
SELECT `Date`,`Headline` FROM testtable WHERE MATCH (Headline) AGAINST ('Apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Gives `null` as a response, but searching for `apple` returns both rows.

So the question is, what is going on here, and more importantly, how do I get the table back to the way it was: a case sensitive fulltext index that gives me separate results for `Apple` and `apple`?

(Using Mysql 5.7, with InnoDB engine)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm still not sure why this happened (the database had not been touched), but re-assigning character set and collation on a column level seems to fix this: `ALTER TABLE testtable MODIFY Headline VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin; `

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

> By default, the search is performed in case-insensitive fashion. To
>   perform a case-sensitive full-text search, use a binary collation for
>   the indexed columns. For example, a column that uses the latin1
>   character set of can be assigned a collation of latin1_bin to make it
>   case-sensitive for full-text searches.

Comment: Yes, this points out I need a case sensitive collation, which I show that I use. Both when creating the index and after dropping it.